# My tab menus exit the page width

Tags: html, css, web, menu

So I'm editting the CSS and the tab menu has a whitespace: nowrap property, which means it doesn't overlap but it ends up exiting the page. Setting the width of the tab menu itself does nothing even with !important and heirarchy CSS.

Looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbmhg.jpg

When I do whitespace: pre, or any of the others they end up overlapping.

Here's the code:

```
html > body > div#header > div#header-bottom-left > ul.tabmenu {
position: absolute;
top: 75px;
left: 700px;
width: 100px !important;
}

#header #header-bottom-left .tabmenu li {
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 11px;
background: url(%%buttons%%) repeat-x;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: What is your intended effect? Do you want them to be cut-off? Or to push down to the next line?

Comment: You ought to be able to set the width of the tabmenu but you also need to make sure its parents are at least as wide as it is if their widths are set.  For example, what is the width of the divs that are the parents of `ul.tabmenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
li {
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

You may try this too

```
ul,li {
   border:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```